# Allow to filter (in a view) on a datetime field of a custom entity

Tags: views, entities

I have created a custom entity as follow:

Here is an extract of my entity definition in  `modules/custom/bank_operation/src/Entity/BankOperation.php`

**Notes**:

1- As you can see, I have changed the value of the `views_data` key

2- The `operation_date` base field have the `datetime` type

```
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "bank_operation",
 
 ...
 
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\bank_operation\BankOperationViewsData",
 
 ...
 
 
class BankOperation extends ContentEntityBase implements BankOperationInterface {

  public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {

    ...
    
    $fields['operation_date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
      ->setLabel(t("Operation date"))
      ->setRequired(TRUE)
      ->setSettings([
        'datetime_type' => DateTimeItem::DATETIME_TYPE_DATE,
      ])

    ...
}
```

Here is an extract of my overrode EntityViewsData in  `modules/custom/bank_operation/src/BankOperationViewsData.php`

This class is used according to the value of the `views_data` key. This is my attempt to allow a view to filter on the `operation_date` field

```
class BankOperationViewsData extends EntityViewsData {

  public function getViewsData() {
    $data = parent::getViewsData();
    $data['bank_operation']['operation_date']['filter'] = [
      'id' => 'datetime',
      'field' => 'operation_date',
      'table' => 'bank_operation',
      'field_name' => 'operation_date',
      'entity_type' => 'bank_operation',
    ];
    return $data;
  }

}
```

After that, I have created a view to display my `BankOperation` entities with an exposed filter on the `operation_date` field.

Here is the error produced when using this filter (I don't understand why `ViewsYearFilterDatetime` is called)

```
Exception: DateTime object not set. in Drupal\Component\Datetime\DateTimePlus->__call() (line 360 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Datetime/DateTimePlus.php). 

Drupal\datetime\Plugin\views\filter\Date->opSimple() (Line: 63)
Drupal\views_year_filter\Plugin\views\filter\ViewsYearFilterDatetime->opSimple() (Line: 330)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\filter\NumericFilter->query() (Line: 1373)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->_build() (Line: 1262)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->build() (Line: 390)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\PathPluginBase->execute() (Line: 180)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\Page->execute() (Line: 1630)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->executeDisplay() (Line: 77)
```

I know that there are other questions like this one, but none of them are providing a detailed answer (only links).

I have setup my question to allow people who are facing the same issue to quickly find a path to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

As there are so many difficulties with base fields (sorting, displaying, filter etc in views), I decided to remove all of them and I re-created them back in the field UI.

To allow this, I set `fieldable = TRUE,` and `field_ui_base_route = some_path` in the annotations of my entity.
This is of course poor design because each field will create a table on its own but I had no time to spend on this...

Feel free to provide a better answer... I think we need a real how-to to provide the same functionalities we have for fields created in UI then for base fields

Edit to add: I have created an issue to create an help item on this topic: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3213021